# Romance Novel about Paint Company CEO

Tags: identification-request

I read part of a book a number of years (8?) back.  It was a romance novel about the CEO of a paint company who marries a Russian (?) Chemist because of passport stuff.  Kinda like a reverse of The Proposal.  It may have been set in Seattle.

The book was a paperback in Novella length, written in English.

The book was probably relatively new at the time.

Answer (score 3):

It could be [*Hired Husband*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9149094.Hired_Husband) by Rebecca Brandewyne.

> With eyes as dark as night and a gaze that laid all secrets bare, Nick
>   Valkov was the kind of man any smart woman would avoid. But dire
>   circumstances forced level-headed Caroline Fortune to proposition this
>   compelling stranger…with marriage. Her family's fate rested in Nick's
>   capable hands—and brilliant mind. Yet her proper upbringing hadn't
>   prepared this reluctant bride for her husband's soul-stirring embrace.
>   And neither expected that their practical union would lead them to
>   dark hours of danger…and the ultimate surrender.

From a [Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2439891933):

> Caroline fortune is the oldest grand-daughter to Kate, who is the
>   matriarch of Fortune companies, including Fortune Cosmetics. When
>   their chief chemist, the Russian Nicholas is threatened by the INS for
>   deportation, Kate and her brothers come up with a pretend marriage
>   plan between Caroline and Nicholas to keep him in the country.